# First and second person pronouns in academic writing

Tags: pronouns

I've been told numerous times in high school that "first and second person pronouns in academic writing" should be avoided. This supposed wisdom is echoed in various style manuals as well. However, if you look at any authoritative text, like

- The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy

[A simple search of "we" will yield countless articles using the first pronoun all throughout.](https://plato.stanford.edu/search/search?query=we)

Given this situation, is it realistic to teach anything stylistically related to using first pronouns? Also, based on experience, trying to stick to this kind of rule damages the entire paper in many ways

- It takes time to conjure up passive tense sentences which usually is all but required to avoid you/we completely
- Some concepts more effectively expressed through these words may fall between the cracks and never see it to fruition, which is truly a shame
- Grades may even suffer trying to stick to the rule -- an irony given that adherence to rules are always motivated by desiring praise and getting good grades, etc.

ad nauseum...

Comment: This is purely a matter of taste; I'm not sure this is a question we can answer in an objective way.

Comment: In philosophy, "we" usually refers to "people in general" and not, as the style guide seems to be implying, the  content creators. As a further point, I suspect "the first person" chiefly refers to "I", rather than "we".

Comment: You should teach to the paper you want to read. But you’ll need to be a vanguard; don’t count on your institution be on the same page.